# UIImage returns nil in UITests

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

in my UITests I want compare image of element with the image from .xcassets:

```
 let referenceImage = UIImage(named: "referenceImage")
 guard  referenceImage != nil else {
    print("didn't find referenceImage image in assets")
    XCTAssert(false)
    return
    }
 let cellImage = myCell.images.elementBoundByIndex(0)
 let imagesEqual = (referenceImage!.isEqual(cellImage))
 XCTAssert(imagesEqual)
```

The `referenceImage` is always nil, although I've added Assets.xcassets to my UITests target (double checked in UITest target->Build phases/Copy bundle resources).

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Works fine here. Sorry :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIImage uses the main bundle to look for the image.
The test bundle is a different bundle.
You should use UIImage's

```
init(named:in:compatibleWith:)
```

where you can specify your test bundle explicitly.

You can get the bundle for the test target with Bundle's [initForClass](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1417717-init) , passing in your current test class.

Comment: Changed it to something like this:
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass:object_getClass(self))
        let referenceImage = UIImage(named: "referenceImage", inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
Thanks!